# error in installing Rsubread package

Tags: r, installation, package, rstudio

I am trying to install 'Rsubread' package but I get this error I am new to R so i am not sure how I should solve it. 
I am using Rstudio on windows 8.1

> source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
>   Bioconductor version 3.2 (BiocInstaller 1.20.1), ?biocLite for help
>   biocLite("Rsubread")
>   BioC_mirror: https://bioconductor.org
>   Using Bioconductor 3.2 (BiocInstaller 1.20.1), R 3.2.3 (2015-12-10).
>   Installing package(s) ‘Rsubread’
>   Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of
>     C/C++/Fortran: ‘Rsubread’
>     These will not be installed

Answer (score 0):

Seems like `Rsubread` is not available for Windows. It needs Mac or Linux.
https://support.bioconductor.org/p/77755/